# React-DOM automatically triggering onClick handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom, react-modal

I have a [react-modal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-modal) which shows some filters. It accepts an `isOpen` prop which hides or shows the Modal as per the value.

The `Modal` opens successfully when clicked on 'Apply' button, but does not close on clicking 'Cancel'.

```
//Click Handlers in the parent component (filters.js)
openAllFilters = () => {
  this.setState({ showAllFilters: true });
};

closeAllFilters = () => {
  this.setState({ showAllFilters: false }, () =>
    console.log("state ", this.state.showAllFilters)
  ); // logs true!);
};

<AllFilters isOpen={this.state.showAllFilters}
    closeAllFilters={this.closeAllFilters}
    onRequestClose={this.closeAllFilters}
    renderAbcFilter={this.renderAbcFilter}
    renderDefFilter={this.renderDefFilter}
    renderXyzFilter={this.renderXyzFilter}
/>
```

The Modal component (AllFilters.js):

```
import React from 'react';
import Modal from 'react-modal';

const RenderFilter = props => {
    return <div className="filter-wrapper">
        <h3 className="filter-title">{props.title}</h3>
        {props.renderFunction()}
    </div>;
}

const AllFilters = (props) => {
    const modalStyles = {
        overlay: {
            zIndex: 200,
        },
        content: {
            top: '0',
            left: '0',
            right: '0',
            bottom: '0',
            padding: '0',
        }
    };

    return (
        <Modal isOpen={props.isOpen}
            style={modalStyles}
            onRequestClose={props.closeAllFilters}>
            <div className="all-filters-container">
                <RenderFilter title='ABC' renderFunction={() => props.renderAbcFilter(false)} />
                <RenderFilter title='XYZ' renderFunction={() => props.renderXyzFilter(false)} />
                <RenderFilter title='DEF' renderFunction={() => props.renderDefFilter(false)} />
            </div>
            <div className="all-filters-footer">
                <button className="button button-secondary filter-cancel-btn " onClick={props.closeAllFilters}>CANCEL</button>
        </Modal >
    )
}

export default AllFilters;
```

I can't figure out why `state` is not updated to `false` when `closeAllFilters` is called? 
EDIT: `closeAllFilters` does get called when 'Cancel' button is clicked. And `console.log(this.state.showAllFilters)` outputs `true`!. Even though this is the `setState` callback!

EDIT2 : I figured that `openAllfilters` is somehow automatically getting called after `closeAllFilters` is invoked. Thus it sets `showAllFilters` back to `true` and the modal remains open. Have updated the question title to better reflect the issue. The stack trace for the same is as follows:

```
openAllFilters (filters.js#382)
callCallback (react-dom.development.js#149)
invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js#199)
invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js#256)
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js#270)
executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js#561)
executeDispatchesInOrder (react-dom.development.js#580)
executeDispatchesAndRelease (react-dom.development.js#680)
executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel (react-dom.development.js#688)
forEachAccumulated (react-dom.development.js#662)
runEventsInBatch (react-dom.development.js#816)
runExtractedEventsInBatch (react-dom.development.js#824)
handleTopLevel (react-dom.development.js#4826)
batchedUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js#20439)
batchedUpdates (react-dom.development.js#2151)
dispatchEvent (react-dom.development.js#4905)
1 (react-dom.development.js#20490)
unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js#255)
interactiveUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js#20489)
interactiveUpdates (react-dom.development.js#2170)
dispatchInteractiveEvent (react-dom.development.js#4882)
```

From above call stack, it seems that React is somehow triggering `openAllFilters`. I went through these function calls one by one, but still can't figure out why it's happening. Maybe someone who understands React source code well might be able to offer some insight..

Comment: So, there must be another part that *maybe* setting the state again to `true` immediately. But, the weird thing is you see "true" from the `setState` calback.

Comment: @devserkan: Yes. That's what puzzled me too. `setState` callbacks are *guaranteed* to give the updated `state` value!

Comment: So, try to debug your app somehow. Look for state changes. Is it going through true->false->true? Also, try to uncomment some parts and until reaching a working state.

Comment: @devserkan: The initial state (`showAllFilters`) is set to `false` inside `constructor`. When Modal opens, state is set to `true` by `openAllFilters`. There is no other code changing the state, other than `closeAllFilters` of course, which is not working, as it's not setting the state back to `false`.

Comment: Well then, it is weird. As I shared before your minimalized code works well. So, try to trim other parts and "Try to find the smallest program that demonstrates the error" as *Bjarne Stroustrup* suggested :)

Comment: Ok so some debugging helped me to figure out that after `closeAllFilters` is called, the execution somehow immediately jumps to `openAllFilters`, which sets the state back to `true`. This is equally weird! The callstack also does not show `closeAllFilters` when the code is paused inside `openAllFilters`. At this point, all the methods on the stack are of `react-dom.development.js`. Which suggests that the DOM node having `onClick` for `openAllFilters` got triggered somehow..?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197672/discussion-between-maverick-and-devserkan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after a lot of debugging and head scratching, I finally figured out what the issue was. `openAllFilters` was getting invoked after call to `closeAllFilters` due to event propagation. The event is triggered by clicking *anywhere* on the modal. I didn't find any prop to disable this behaviour, so maybe it's a bug of `react-modal`. So the only fix required was to add `e.stopPropagation()`!

So the changed method becomes:

```
closeAllFilters = (e) => {
    this.setState({ showAllFilters: false });
    e.stopPropagation();
}
```

Thanks for all the help though!

Comment: Thanks for sharing the cause of the problem. This is still weird. I'm using `react-modal` and close handler is not triggered like that. Even, I'm using `onRequestClose` and `shouldCloseOnOverlayClick` as you do since I want to close the model by clicking the overlay. I haven't encountered a problem like yours. The close handler shouldn't be triggered by clicking everywhere I guess, just the overlay. Am I getting this wrong?

Comment: @devserkan Maybe this behaviour is unique to my app only. But when I ran the code step-by-step after `closeAllFilters` is invoked, I found that the code immediately moves inside `react-modal.js`, where it goes through a few functions, and then directly goes inside `openAllFilters`.