# Since updating react-dom and react-router-dom packages: behaviors executing additional times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

I've inherited a react/node/prismic application where we need to update the prismic-reactjs package, which resulted in needing to update a few others- in total, we changed:

prismic-reactjs: 0.2.0 → 1.1.0

react: 15.6.1 → 16.0.0

webpack: 3.12.0 → 4.39.2

react-dom: 15.6.1 → 16.0.0

react-router-dom: 4.1.2 → 5.0.1

extract-text-webpack-plugin (deprecated) → mini-css-extract-plugin

Then removed one use of "withRouter()" because of new error when starting up the local server (but I confirmed in another branch that making that edit alone doesn't produce the symptom below)

**Context**: we have a personMap that shows a icons for a set of people, and you click one of them to open a PersonMapStory modal, which shows that person's story, then links to everybody else in a list at the bottom. If you scroll down and click one of those links, the story up top is replaced accordingly (with the new person's story), and list below is everyone else. In the code, the button onClick behavior for these bottom links is setActivePerson() to this new person.

**New bug**: in this new branch, when I have the story modal open and simply hover off the page and back again, we're repeating the setQueuedUpPerson and setNoQueuedUpPerson calls that are associated with onMouseEnter and onMouseLeave. (Doesn't happen in the previous/production code). It's causing downstream problems and I'm trying to figure out how to prevent this.

**Further info**: I've already seen a [propagation issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58530473/since-updating-react-dom-and-react-router-dom-packages-excessive-li-onclick-beh) where the solution was to pass the event and call stopPropagation in the appropriate method, and this seems like the same kind of behavior. Is there a way to do the same sort of thing to have it stop listening to the hover behavior when the modal is up?

Updated PersonMap.js (from first suggested answer):

```
import Modal from 'react-modal'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import React from 'react'

import PersonMapPoint from './PersonMapPoint'
import PersonMapStory from './PersonMapStory'
import PersonMapCallout from './PersonMapCallout'
import PersonMapLocator from './PersonMapLocator'
import PersonMapBackground from './PersonMapBackground'

const CUSTOM_STYLES = {
    content: {
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        bottom: 0,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        zIndex: 10,
        border: 'none'
    }
}

class PersonMap extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.setActivePerson = this.setActivePerson.bind(this)
        this.setNoActivePerson = this.setNoActivePerson.bind(this)
        this.setQueuedUpPerson = this.setQueuedUpPerson.bind(this)
        this.setNoQueuedUpPerson = this.setNoQueuedUpPerson.bind(this)
        this.checkBlurEvent = this.checkBlurEvent.bind(this)
        this.setIsDesktop = this.setIsDesktop.bind(this)
        this.checkHasBeenScrolledTo = this.checkHasBeenScrolledTo.bind(this)
        this.setTopRef = this.setTopRef.bind(this)
        this.handleKeyPress = this.handleKeyPress.bind(this)

        this.state = {
            activePerson: null,
            queuedUpPerson: null,
            scrollPos: 0,
            isDesktop: false,
            hasBeenScrolledTo: false,
            lastQueuedPerson: null
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setIsDesktop()
        this.checkHasBeenScrolledTo()
        window.addEventListener('resize', this.setIsDesktop)
        window.addEventListener('scroll', this.checkHasBeenScrolledTo)
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        window.removeEventListener('resize', this.setIsDesktop)
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.checkHasBeenScrolledTo)
    }

    setTopRef(element) {
        this.topRef = element
    }

    setActivePerson(personName) {
        this.setState({
            activePerson: personName,
            scrollPos: window.scrollY
        })
    }

    setNoActivePerson() {
        this.setState({
            queuedUpPerson: this.state.activePerson,
            activePerson: null
        }, () => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                window.scrollTo(0, this.state.scrollPos)
            }, 50)
        })
    }

    setQueuedUpPerson(e, personName) {
        this.setState({
            queuedUpPerson: personName,
            lastQueuedPerson: personName
        })
        e.stopPropagation()
    }

    setNoQueuedUpPerson(e) {
        this.setState({
            queuedUpPerson: null
        })
        e.stopPropagation()
    }

    handleKeyPress(e, name) {
        if (e.key !== ' ' && e.key !== 'Enter') {
            return
        }
        this.setActivePerson(name)
    }

    checkBlurEvent(e) {
        if (Array.from(e.currentTarget.childNodes[0].childNodes).includes(e.relatedTarget)) {
            return
        }
        this.setNoQueuedUpPerson(e)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <section className="slice-area person-map CONSTRAIN">
                <div className="person-map-headers">
                    <div className="person-map-headers-inner">
                        <h1 className="person-map-title">
                            {this.props.title}
                        </h1>
                        <p className="person-map-disclaimer">
                            {this.props.disclaimer}
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {
                    !this.state.isDesktop &&
                    <div className="person-map-graphic" ref={this.setTopRef}>
                        {
                            this.props.personStories.map(person => (
                                <PersonMapLocator
                                    x={person.x}
                                    y={person.y}
                                    key={person.name}
                                >
                                    <PersonMapPoint name={person.name}/>
                                </PersonMapLocator>
                            ))
                        }
                        <PersonMapBackground isVisible={this.state.hasBeenScrolledTo} />
                    </div>
                }
                <div
                    className={`person-map-list-wrap${ this.state.isDesktop ? ' --desktop' : '' }`}
                    ref={this.state.isDesktop && this.setTopRef}
                >
                    { this.state.isDesktop &&
                        <PersonMapBackground isVisible={this.state.hasBeenScrolledTo}/>
                    }
                    <ul className="person-map-list">
                        {
                            this.props.personStories.map((person) => {
                                const thisPersonIsQueued = this.state.queuedUpPerson === person.name
                                const thisPersonIsActive = this.state.activePerson === person.name
                                const thisPersonWasLastQueued = this.state.lastQueuedPerson === person.name

                                return (
                                    <li
                                        key={person.name} className={`person-map-list-item${thisPersonWasLastQueued ? ' --active' : ''}`}
                                        onMouseEnter={this.state.isDesktop ? (e) => this.setQueuedUpPerson(e, person.name) : null}
                                        onMouseLeave={this.state.isDesktop ? this.setNoQueuedUpPerson : null}
                                        onFocus={this.state.isDesktop ? (e) => this.setQueuedUpPerson(e, person.name) : null}
                                        onBlur={this.state.isDesktop ? this.checkBlurEvent : null}
                                        onClick={thisPersonIsQueued || !this.state.isDesktop ? () => this.setActivePerson(person.name) : null}
                                        onKeyPress={(e) => this.handleKeyPress(e, person.name)}
                                    >
                                        {
                                            this.state.isDesktop ?
                                                <PersonMapLocator
                                                    x={person.x}
                                                    y={person.y}
                                                >
                                                    <PersonMapPoint
                                                        name={person.name}
                                                        isInteractive
                                                        isActive={thisPersonIsQueued}
                                                        imageUrl={person.photo_url}
                                                    />
                                                    <PersonMapCallout
                                                        name={person.name}
                                                        photo={person.photo_url}
                                                        isOpen={thisPersonIsQueued}
                                                        isDesktop
                                                    />
                                                </PersonMapLocator> :
                                                <PersonMapCallout
                                                    name={person.name}
                                                    photo={person.photo_url}
                                                />
                                        }
                                        <Modal
                                            isOpen={thisPersonIsActive}
                                            onRequestClose={this.setNoActivePerson}
                                            style={CUSTOM_STYLES}
                                        >
                                            <PersonMapStory
                                                name={person.name}
                                                photo={person.photo_url}
                                                story={person.story}
                                                setNoActivePerson={this.setNoActivePerson}
                                                setActivePerson={this.setActivePerson}
                                                isActive={thisPersonIsActive}
                                                otherPersons={this.props.personStories.filter((item) => item.name !== person.name).map((item) => ({ name: item.name, photo: item.photo_url }))}
                                                isDesktop={this.state.isDesktop}
                                            />
                                        </Modal>
                                    </li>
                                )
                            })
                        }
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </section>
        )
    }
}

PersonMap.propTypes = {
    title: PropTypes.string,
    disclaimer: PropTypes.string,
    personStories: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
        name: PropTypes.string,
        photo_url: PropTypes.string,
        x: PropTypes.number,
        y: PropTypes.number,
        story: PropTypes.shape({
            title: PropTypes.string,
            link: PropTypes.string,
            content: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
                question: PropTypes.string,
                answer: PropTypes.string
            }))
        })
    }))
}

export default PersonMap
```

Original PersonMap.js:

```
import Modal from 'react-modal'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import React from 'react'

import PersonMapPoint from './PersonMapPoint'
import PersonMapStory from './PersonMapStory'
import PersonMapCallout from './PersonMapCallout'
import PersonMapLocator from './PersonMapLocator'
import PersonMapBackground from './PersonMapBackground'

const CUSTOM_STYLES = {
    content: {
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        bottom: 0,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        zIndex: 10,
        border: 'none'
    }
}

class PersonMap extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.setActivePerson = this.setActivePerson.bind(this)
        this.setNoActivePerson = this.setNoActivePerson.bind(this)
        this.setQueuedUpPerson = this.setQueuedUpPerson.bind(this)
        this.setNoQueuedUpPerson = this.setNoQueuedUpPerson.bind(this)
        this.checkBlurEvent = this.checkBlurEvent.bind(this)
        this.setIsDesktop = this.setIsDesktop.bind(this)
        this.checkHasBeenScrolledTo = this.checkHasBeenScrolledTo.bind(this)
        this.setTopRef = this.setTopRef.bind(this)
        this.handleKeyPress = this.handleKeyPress.bind(this)

        this.state = {
            activePerson: null,
            queuedUpPerson: null,
            scrollPos: 0,
            isDesktop: false,
            hasBeenScrolledTo: false,
            lastQueuedPerson: null
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setIsDesktop()
        this.checkHasBeenScrolledTo()
        window.addEventListener('resize', this.setIsDesktop)
        window.addEventListener('scroll', this.checkHasBeenScrolledTo)
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        window.removeEventListener('resize', this.setIsDesktop)
        window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.checkHasBeenScrolledTo)
    }

    setTopRef(element) {
        this.topRef = element
    }

    setActivePerson(personName) {
        this.setState({
            activePerson: personName,
            scrollPos: window.scrollY
        })
        event.stopPropagation()
    }

    setNoActivePerson() {
        this.setState({
            queuedUpPerson: this.state.activePerson,
            activePerson: null
        }, () => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                window.scrollTo(0, this.state.scrollPos)
            }, 50)
        })
    }

    setQueuedUpPerson(personName) {
        this.setState({
            queuedUpPerson: personName,
            lastQueuedPerson: personName
        })
    }

    setNoQueuedUpPerson() {
        this.setState({
            queuedUpPerson: null
        })
        event.stopPropagation()
    }

    handleKeyPress(e, name) {
        if (e.key !== ' ' && e.key !== 'Enter') {
            return
        }
        this.setActivePerson(name)
    }

    checkBlurEvent(e) {
        if (Array.from(e.currentTarget.childNodes[0].childNodes).includes(e.relatedTarget)) {
            return
        }
        this.setNoQueuedUpPerson()
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <section className="slice-area person-map CONSTRAIN">
                <div className="person-map-headers">
                    <div className="person-map-headers-inner">
                        <h1 className="person-map-title">
                            {this.props.title}
                        </h1>
                        <p className="person-map-disclaimer">
                            {this.props.disclaimer}
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div
                    className={`person-map-list-wrap${ this.state.isDesktop ? ' --desktop' : '' }`}
                    ref={this.state.isDesktop && this.setTopRef}
                >
                    { this.state.isDesktop &&
                        <PersonMapBackground isVisible={this.state.hasBeenScrolledTo}/>
                    }
                    <ul className="person-map-list">
                        {
                            this.props.personStories.map((person) => {
                                const thisPersonIsQueued = this.state.queuedUpPerson === person.name
                                const thisPersonIsActive = this.state.activePerson === person.name
                                const thisPersonWasLastQueued = this.state.lastQueuedPerson === person.name

                                return (
                                    <li
                                        key={person.name} className={`person-map-list-item${thisPersonWasLastQueued ? ' --active' : ''}`}
                                        onMouseEnter={this.state.isDesktop ? () => this.setQueuedUpPerson(person.name) : null}
                                        onMouseLeave={this.state.isDesktop ? this.setNoQueuedUpPerson : null}
                                        onFocus={this.state.isDesktop ? () => this.setQueuedUpPerson(person.name) : null}
                                        onBlur={this.state.isDesktop ? this.checkBlurEvent : null}
                                        onClick={thisPersonIsQueued || !this.state.isDesktop ? () => this.setActivePerson(person.name) : null}
                                        onKeyPress={(e) => this.handleKeyPress(e, person.name)}
                                    >
                                        {
                                                <PersonMapLocator
                                                    x={person.x}
                                                    y={person.y}
                                                >
                                        }
                                        <Modal
                                            isOpen={thisPersonIsActive}
                                            onRequestClose={this.setNoActivePerson}
                                            style={CUSTOM_STYLES}
                                        >
                                            <PersonMapStory
                                                name={person.name}
                                                photo={person.photo_url}
                                                story={person.story}
                                                setNoActivePerson={this.setNoActivePerson}
                                                setActivePerson={this.setActivePerson}
                                                isActive={thisPersonIsActive}
                                                otherPersons={this.props.personStories.filter((item) => item.name !== person.name).map((item) => ({ name: item.name, photo: item.photo_url }))}
                                                isDesktop={this.state.isDesktop}
                                            />
                                        </Modal>
                                    </li>
                                )
                            })
                        }
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </section>
        )
    }
}

PersonMap.propTypes = {
    title: PropTypes.string,
    disclaimer: PropTypes.string,
    personStories: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
        name: PropTypes.string,
        photo_url: PropTypes.string,
        x: PropTypes.number,
        y: PropTypes.number,
        story: PropTypes.shape({
            title: PropTypes.string,
            link: PropTypes.string,
            content: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
                question: PropTypes.string,
                answer: PropTypes.string
            }))
        })
    }))
}
export default PersonMap
```

PersonMapStory.js:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import React from 'react'

import PersonMapPerson from './PersonMapPerson'


class PersonMapStory extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        console.log("PersonMapStory constructor")
        super(props)

        this.deactivateThisPerson = this.deactivateThisPerson.bind(this)
        this.check = 0
    }

    deactivateThisPerson(backPressed = false) {
        if (!backPressed) {
            history.back()
        }
        console.log("Set no active person ")
        this.props.setNoActivePerson()
    }

    setActivePerson(name) {
        this.props.setActivePerson(name)
        event.stopPropagation()
    }


    componentDidMount() {
        const loc = window.location.pathname.substr(1)
        this.setState({ location: loc })
        const openState = { modalOpen: true }
        history.pushState(openState, 'signup-open', loc)
      }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className={`person-map-story${this.props.isActive ? ' --active' : ''}${this.props.isDesktop ? ' --desktop' : ''}`}>
                <h2 className="person-map-story-title">
                    { this.props.story.title }
                </h2>
                <button className="person-map-story-close-button" onClick={() => {this.deactivateThisPerson(false)}}>
                    <span className="person-map-story-close-button-text">
                        Close Story
                    </span>
                </button>
                <div className="person-map-story-body">
                    <span className="person-map-story-person-wrap">
                        <PersonMapPerson
                            photo={this.props.photo}
                            name={this.props.name}
                        />
                    </span>
                    {
                        this.props.story.content.map((section) => {
                            if (section) {
                                return (
                                    <div key={section.question}>
                                        <h3 className="person-map-story-question">{section.question}</h3>
                                        <p className="person-map-story-answer">
                                            {section.answer}
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                )
                            }
                        })
                    }
                    {
                        this.props.story.link &&
                        <a  href={this.props.story.link}
                            target="_blank"
                            className="person-map-story-more-link header-and-text-link"
                        >  Read More Stories
                        </a>
                    }

                    <ul className="person-map-story-other-list">
                        {
                            this.props.otherPersons.map((person) => (
                                <li
                                    key={person.name}
                                    className="person-map-story-other-list-item"
                                >
                                    <button className="person-map-story-other-button" onClick={() => this.setActivePerson(person.name)}>
                                        <PersonMapPerson
                                            name={person.name}
                                            photo={person.photo}
                                            ctaText="View their story"
                                        />
                                    </button>
                                </li>
                            ))
                        }
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

PersonMapStory.propTypes = {
    name: PropTypes.string,
    photo: PropTypes.string,
    story: PropTypes.shape({
        title: PropTypes.string,
        link: PropTypes.string,
        content: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
            question: PropTypes.string,
            answer: PropTypes.string
        }))
    }),
    setNoActivePerson: PropTypes.func,
    setActivePerson: PropTypes.func,
    isActive: PropTypes.bool,
    otherPersons: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
        name: PropTypes.string,
        photo: PropTypes.string
    })),
    isDesktop: PropTypes.bool
}

export default PersonMapStory
```

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE (as below does not work):

Could you key off there being an `activePerson` in `state` as to whether the modal is open or not, which would mean you wouldn't want `setQueuedUpPerson` or `setNoQueuedUpPerson` to call? Either change them like this:

```
setQueuedUpPerson(e, personName) {
    if(!this.state.activePerson) {
      this.setState({
          queuedUpPerson: personName,
          lastQueuedPerson: personName
      })
    }

    e.stopPropagation()
}

setNoQueuedUpPerson(e) {
    if(!this.state.activePerson) {
      this.setState({
          queuedUpPerson: null
      })
    }
    e.stopPropagation()
}
```

Or make the `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave` events null if there is an `activePerson`?

---

You should be able to change

```
onMouseEnter={this.state.isDesktop ? () => this.setQueuedUpPerson(person.name) : null}
```

to

```
onMouseEnter={this.state.isDesktop ? (e) => this.setQueuedUpPerson(e,person.name) : null}
```

And then access the event as with your previous question to stop propagation:

```
setQueuedUpPerson(event, personName) {
    this.setState({
        queuedUpPerson: personName,
        lastQueuedPerson: personName
    })
    event.stopPropagation()
}
```

With `onMouseLeave`, you just need to add the `event` parameter to your function as it is already exposed since you are passing the function reference directly, as opposed to calling it from an anonymous function like with `onMouseEnter`:

```
setNoQueuedUpPerson(event) {
    this.setState({
        queuedUpPerson: null
    })
    event.stopPropagation()
}
```

Comment: thanks @Anthony! I've made these changes (and the calls from setNoQueuedUpPerson and the onFocus behavior), but the behavior is still the same: after opening a person’s story, if I roll the cursor outside the modal we call setNoQueuedUpPatient and render().  And when I bring the cursor back we call SetQueuedUpPatient and render(). (And the extra render calls make problems). In the live code nothing happens when we mouse out/in of the modal window, so I’m trying to get back to that behavior. Any other ideas? I'll paste my updated code in case I did something wrong. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: I updated with another possible approach, but really hard for me to diagnose with about being able to debug and play around with it myself. Another possible idea would be to add mouseEnter/mouseLeave handlers to the modal and just make them `stopPropagation` so the events never reach the `<li>`

Comment: Of course- I just updated the onMouseEnter and onMouseLeave to have one more condition to not do anything if the modal is open- (&& !thisPatientIsActive)- and that's it, working like a charm! (didn't even need stopPropagation). I can't thank you enough for taking the time to think this through and make suggestions. Sometimes when something is new, the lack of familiarity makes it feel mysterious and daunting, but even if it looks different at the end of the day it's just logic!